# How to disable potion effects such as the slowness FOV

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I'm playing minecraft and things like nausea randomly happen on servers i play on. My game does not respond to this well. Is there a way to disable this? I looked at Mojang's help page and got no help from it. Thanks.

Comment: if they randomly happen (no apparent cause) then you are likely getting trolled with command blocks or something like that

Answer (score 11):

There is no way to disable these effects in the settings. This is because these effects change game-play and it wouldn't be fair if some players had it turned off and some had it turned on.

Although if you drink a bucket of milk in game any potion effects will go away.

> [Milk](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Milk) will immediately cure the player of any status (potion) effects.

Comment: If they're being constantly applied, though, milk won't do much.

Comment: @peper757 And if it's happening through the use of plugins, milk will most likely not solve the problem.

Comment: Milk is right but it will take away positive effects.